# Compatible version of Ubuntu 64 bit with Intel processor

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I want to know which version of Ubuntu is compatible with my machine.

My PC configuration is:

Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo
RAM : 3 GB
System Type : 64-bit

I have currently installed Windows 7 in my machine. Now I want to install Ubuntu 64 bit as well. So that I can get Opportunity to use both the systems one by one.
I have tried with [ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso) but getting error in installation.
I want to know which version of Ubuntu is compatible with my machine?
Should I go with [ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) ?

Comment: Both versions are compatible with your system, though the 32 bit one will sometimes work better. What's the error message you get?

Comment: some den file was not gonna install it was the error.

Comment: I recommend you carefully note the exact error message and ask a question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). But try to install the i386 image first, it should work fine on your system.

Answer (score 2):

The AMD64 version of Ubuntu is compatible with EM64T processors.

Comment: Whee! The truth gets a downvote. Awesome.

Comment: Might be true, but it's clearly doesn't answer the question or help the user. :) See also: [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image) and [Core i7 with 4GB - go 64 bit or stay 32bit..?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14511/core-i7-with-4gb-go-64-bit-or-stay-32bit)